# git log --tags changes the commits order

Tags: git, git-log

By default, `git log` the commits are shown in reverse chronological order.

```
commit 519f71eb2e4e1fa5da429bb01f95d2b6517c4c34
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:05 2015 +1100

    Fourth commit

commit d52ef03bbdb825499ed317172eacb29d6666cb13
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:04 2015 +1100

    Third commit

commit 4992115ed36e0a2135f1ea5bfc6bd6d4aa6ba97a
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:03 2015 +1100

    Second commit

commit 9fc40f59a209c17cb8554afd4476c14126f22ad8
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:03 2015 +1100

    First commit
```

But if I run `git log --tags` the commits order is different

```
commit 519f71eb2e4e1fa5da429bb01f95d2b6517c4c34
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:05 2015 +1100

    Fourth commit

commit d52ef03bbdb825499ed317172eacb29d6666cb13
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:04 2015 +1100

    Third commit

commit 9fc40f59a209c17cb8554afd4476c14126f22ad8
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:03 2015 +1100

    First commit

commit 4992115ed36e0a2135f1ea5bfc6bd6d4aa6ba97a
Author: Steve Mao <maochenyan@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:03 2015 +1100

    Second commit
```

According to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

> --tags[=<pattern>]
>   Pretend as if all the refs in refs/tags are listed on the command line as <commit>. If <pattern> is given, limit tags to ones matching given shell glob. If pattern lacks `?`, `*`, or `[`, `/*` at the end is implied.

It doesn't mention the order. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The time stamps on the first two commits appear to be identical:

```
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:03 2015 +1100
Date:   Fri Dec 25 21:07:03 2015 +1100
```

(the default sort is based on the *commit* time stamp, and this shows the *author* time stamp, so I can't prove that the two invisible time stamps are the same, but this is pretty suggestive since with ordinary commits the author and commit dates are the same).

Given that the time stamps are the same, sorting by time stamp won't provide a specific order.  Lacking that specific order, we might expect that git would use a [stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts), and thus show commits as specified on the command line before commits with the same time stamp that were found by following parent links.  Hence, if there's a tag pointing to commit `9fc40f5...` ("First commit"), and you gave that on the command line (via `--tags`), we could expect that commit to come before `4992115...`.

(The documentation doesn't actually claim that it uses a stable sort in the first place either, but if the sort isn't stable, we should expect equal-timestamps to get shuffled semi-randomly in either case.)

Note that adding `--topo-order` (or `--graph`, which implies `--topo-order`) should force an output closer to what I think you're expecting.

Comment: Lol what. Yes these commits are created by a bot but the operations are in sync. So I thought although the timestamps are the same but they were created in order.

Comment: Let me try it a different way.  `git log` means `git log HEAD` but `git log --tags` means `git log tag1 tag2 tag3 ...`.  The first puts the `HEAD` commit into the list of all commits to show, then adds (in time order) additional commits reachable from `HEAD`, newer ones in front of `HEAD` and same-date-or-older after `HEAD`.  The second puts the specific tags into the list, then adds reachable commits, newer ones going in front and same-date-or-older going after.  With two that have the exact same date stamp they wind up in what you think of as the "wrong" order; there's no "before" to fix it.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't mean to *defend* the `git log` output for this case, just to *explain* it.  I think it should do a topological sort in more cases -- at the very least, to break ties in cases like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Note there is another case where `git log --tags` changes the output: when you query tags for a non-existing pattern (so for tags which does not exists).
This has been fixed in Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017)

See [commit 5d34d1a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d34d1ac06fe70fc0a7a8f35ddf9e7690114dda7), [commit 0159ba3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0159ba3226f75fbd6d3dc0e92c325cb11f2f0699), [commit 7ba8262](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ba826290aa448bb9d0d45c3bb4b34905b741013), [commit 0c5dc74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c5dc7431a01d325e815ce722d80ad549a41e632) (02 Aug 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8fbaf0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fbaf0b13bc54819445f613e917c44ea52eef804), 11 Aug 2017)</sup>

> "`git log --tag=no-such-tag`" showed `log` starting from `HEAD`, which
>   has been fixed---it now shows nothing.